# Unable to properly import spring boot project after intelij update

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle

Ive recently upgrade my IDE (Intellij ver 2017.2) to the latest version, from some reason after it was installed my project was not imported and I had to re import it manual however in every way I tried to import (gradle/spring) it, I noticed that all my dependencies are not imported automatically and I have to re import them manually. does anyone experience this issue? How can I re import my project properly? The project is gradle based.

Comment: Do you mean that Gradle project refresh didn't work? What exactly did you do to fix it?

Comment: Did you already try `Reimport all gradle projects` (little refresh icon in the Gradle tool window) and `File` -> `Invalidate caches / restart`?

Comment: Yes, tried refresh and invalidate caches (which I though might work at first) but still, every class file that I open I see that all dependencies are unknown, I am wiling to re import the entire project if necessary but I need to know the correct path

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors.

Comment: I can see many exceptions there, one of them is 2017-07-30 20:54:31,315 [17424361]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2-all.zip'. what else should I look for?

Comment: Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176336.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on refresh icon that reimports all the dependencies for the project.

[image]

Comment: Tried that already, but it did not had any effect, any other ideas?